# PMF of Matching Problem Hats

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, density-function

This is a variation of a famous problem, that I have heard before but I have never seen it in this format before.

> $N$ Guests arrive at a party, each wearing a hat. We collect all the hats and then randomly redistribute the hats, giving each person one of the $N$ has randomly. Letting $X_N$ be the number of hats that are matched correctly, what is the $PMF$ of $X_N$? I.e. 
>   $P(X_N=k)=$

The common variations of this problem that I have seen usually involve the probability that no one gets the correct hat or as $N$ approaches $\infty$. I am struggling to identify a distribution that would result in any type of general formula for $PMF$ of this random variable. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: As I'm sure you know, $P(X_N=0)=D_N/N!$ where the $D_N$ are the derangement numbers. In general $P(X_N=k)$ can be expressed in terms of derangement numbers.

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly check if that is what you intend to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of  [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ item has the following formula

$$D_n = n! \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Let's consider how many cases that would satisfy $k$ hats being matched.

We first select $k$ people of which their hats are to be matched $\binom{N}{k}$ and then we compute the possible number of derangement for the other $N-k$ of the students, $D_{N-k}$

Hence \begin{align}Pr(X_N=k)&=\frac{\binom{N}{k}D_{N-k}}{N!} 
\\
&=\frac{\binom{N}{k}(N-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{N-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}{N!}\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{N-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\end{align}